# Post-merge accounts I do not receive reputation

Tags: support, bug, user-accounts

I recently made a request to merge my account and it just went through -- my posts and reputation from my old account has been merged with my current one. However, I do not receive any reputation for anything I have done. I have answered a few questions and received quite a few up votes -- it does not show +10 (like it should) for each upvote on my reputation tab, it's just blank.

How can this be fixed?

An example of this is I answered a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239634/how-to-copy-local-variable-to-global-variable-if-both-have-the-same-array-names/18239713#18239713) and I have not received any of the reputation for my answer and the corresponding up votes.

Comment: You hit the rep cap. Congrats!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, I think I am far from that cap :)

Comment: @JacobPollack the rep cap is 200 reputation per day (ignoring bounties and accepts). which you hit

Comment: @FDinoff, oh I did not know that. So what happens tomorrow when that resets? -- do I get the up votes? Is there a doc that you can link me to so I can review all of these specifics.

Comment: Under Additionally: "You can earn a maximum of +200 reputation from upvotes and suggested edits in any given day. Accepted answers and bounties are counted separately (source). Reputation "lost" from the reputation cap is not awarded on following days."

Comment: I think we should have another FAQ entry regarding just the rep cap. Considering how many times these questions are asked. **Or**, we could push a system-wide notification (Stack Exchange Multi-Collider Dropdown(tm)) the first time someone hits the rep cap.